# How to load data for a barplot from a dataframe using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

So I have a dataframe named `df1` that I used pandas to import the CSV file into my Jupyter notebook. I now want to display the results of this dataframe in the form of a bar plot. At the moment I am just manually doing it by inserting the figures like this: `data = [120,52,50]`. How do I refer to the dataframe `df1` instead? I have tried, but it doesn't seem as simple as it should be.

This is the dataframe called `df1`:

```
+---+---------+---------+
|   | column1 | column2 |
+---+---------+---------+
| 0 |      A  |   120   |
| 1 |      B  |   52    |
| 2 |      C  |   50    |
+---+---------+---------+
```

```py
    import matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, random as rd, 
    pandas as pd, seaborn as sns
    %matplotlib inline

# import CSV to dataframe

    df1 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
    df1

# generate barplot

    data = [120,52,50]
    columns = 0,1,2
    bars = ("bar1", "bar2", "bar3")
    plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
    b = plt.bar(columns,data,width = 0.8, color = ('#569cff','#82b5ff','#b5d1ff'))
    plt.xticks(columns,bars)
    plt.legend(b,bars,fontsize=14)
    plt.title("title goes here",fontsize=16)
    plt.ylabel('y label',fontsize=12)
    plt.xlabel('x label',fontsize=12)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a simple bar chart, try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'column1': ('A','B','C'),'column2':(120,52,50)}).set_index('column1')
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: But how do I do it so I am not having to enter in the figures manually? The barchart should be generated by using what is in the dataframe.